# How to get the Exchange Rate based on the Closing Date in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Table Exchange Rate containing the Date in Date/Time format and the exchange rate. I want to get the exchange rate based on the max of date.
For Example:

```
Date: 22/07/2019 11:00    Exchange Rate: 77.83
      22/07/2019 11:45                   75.00
      17/07/2019 12:00                   90.00
```

Now I need to get the result as 77.83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a new measure:

```
LatestExchangeRate = 
var maxDate = MAX(rateTable['Date'])

return 
CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDVALUE(rateTable['Exchange Rate']), 
    FILTER(
        rateTable, 
        rateTable['Date'] = maxDate
    )
)
```

Explanation:
We filter the table by maxDate and get a single row. From this single row we select the Exchange Rate

Comment: Thank u so much for your help. I was trying to fetch by using Max(rateTable[Exchange Rate] that is why I was getting wrong. Thank u again @Aldert